# Jupyter Notebooks Python - Import text from text path as string

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I'm able to import text as a string. I understand also read_csv.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

My question is if I data frame with many records, and I have the text location. How can bulk import text as strings to a new column?

Example data frame:

```
Filename,Text Path
File1,C:\Text\File1.txt
File2,C:\Text\File2.txt
File3,C:\Text\File3.txt
```

Example Result:

```
Filename,Text Path,Text
File1,C:\Text\File1.txt,This is some text.
File2,C:\Text\File2.txt,Other kinds of text.
File3,C:\Text\File3.txt,Even more text.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any library that can do this directly.  I think you need to step through each row of the dataframe and add the text to a new column.  Assuming you are using pandas and your example dataframe is "df":

```
for i in range(len(df['Text Path'])):
    with open(df.loc[i,'Text Path'], 'r') as file:
        df.loc[i,'Text'] = file.read()
```

EDIT:

this could be a bit faster (apply a function to generate the new column):

```
def readtxt(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()

df['Text'] = df['Text Path'].apply(readtxt)
```